# How to use SSE instruction in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sse

I want to operate(sum) two 2d-vectors(NumPy.array) in python 3.
I know I can use functions in NumPy, but I still want to know is there any package to support SSE instruction opreation in python 3? or any existing package with high efficiency to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's `numpy-mkl` which is Numpy compiled against Intel's Math Kernel Library.